# Designing an iOS App to run for specific iOS versions

Tags: ios, app-store

So, we are developing an iOS App which will be a medical device.  Therefore it must be verified to FDA regulations, and this will be for a specific iOS version.  We are learning that it is difficult to prevent the end user to update the iOS version, and this is a problem because from the FDA's perspective, you will then be running in an unverified state.

So, it looks like we will be have to re-verify our App when iOS updates, because we have to assume our iPads (even though a controlled environment) are updating.  Which is fine.  But in the meantime we need to not let users run our App.

So... I'm putting in some code in our App that checks "NSFoundationVersionNumber" and will disable itself (with an alert) if the iOS is later than the one verified against.

My question is, since I've never seen an App do this, is: is this a reasonable approach, and is it good/bad practice?  Will Apple (who seems to be interested in keeping everyone in lockstep) have an issue with this during App review?

Comment: If it's an App Store app, don't expect Apple to approve it.

Comment: If you get an app approved by Apple for the current official iOS release, then it's already approved and will remain in the App Store, even if Apple updates their OS.  However if you submit an update, you will have to make sure the update runs under the newer OS version.  You may also find angry existing customers who auto-update their OS and find your app dead.  One star reviews may await.

Comment: A solution to this is to implement a view that will block the application if it confirms it's being used with a version that is not yet approved by the FDA.

Answer (score 0):

As an existence proof, there are plenty of apps in the iOS App store that ran under some previous iOS version, but just crash under the latest iOS update. Apple does not seem to remove these apps if they were approved when that earlier OS version was the latest official release.  Fixing these crashes is a very common reason given in app update descriptions.

So submitting an app that only runs on the current release version of iOS (and no later versions) may not be 'best practice', but it happens, and is thus possible.

However, you will have a problem if you submit something to the FDA which requires a certain iOS version, and Apple updates their OS during the approval process, and thus no longer sells or supports installing that older OS version shortly thereafter.  You will never be able to release your FDA approved app for any available customer iOS devices.  Apple updates iOS versions quite often.

It is also possible (has occasionally been reported) for Apple to test submitted apps under a beta of the next iOS release, and reject apps that do not run on this beta.

Answer (score 0):

On the iOS platform, where programming and design paradigms are at least partially dictated by Apple, I would say that this could indeed be considered *bad practice*.

Though this scenario does not seem to be explicitly addressed in [**Apple's Review Guidelines**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), juding the spirit of that document (especially regarding "**Apps containing content or services that expire after a limited time**"), I'd expect them to take offense in an app that is *designed* to offer no functionality for certain devices, and especially one that is *designed* to offer no functionality by default after the device is updated to the newest version of iOS.

As a possible alternate strategy I'd suggest implementing the version check like you described, but instead of shutting down, in the event of encountering a non-verified iOS version the app could merely inform the user about it (and the consequences thereof), but continue to function nominally (maybe with prominent warning marks displayed on the screen).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps checking the iOS version at startup in your delegate could do what you want.

[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion] in iOS 8 and above.

Set a specific version in a variable and if the version is newer disable the app.

There are a few ways to disable it. Disable items and navigation on the mainViewController...